# Script to automatically write file upon extracting some folder

Tags: scripts, tar

I want to write script that will run in background and do following task:
As soon as I extract "xyz.tar.gz" file to desktop it should write "a.cpp" file to desktop,and if a.cpp file already presents on desktop it should replace existing file..please help..stuck since hour..tar file name and file to be written are specific so it can hardcoded in script..

Answer (score 1):

`inotify-tools` package contains command-line tools to monitor file modification messages from kernel's inotify module. You can use `inotifywait` to monitor some file for changes

```
inotifywait filename.ext
```

the script will block at this line and will only continue when the file is modified.

Just a general idea... the script would look something like

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ] 
do
    inotifywait ~/Desktop/filename.ext
    echo "Hello" > ~/Desktop/a.cpp
done
```